# Programs scaling small on high resolution display

Tags: windows-8, resolution

I recently purchased an Acer Aspire S7-392. It has a 2560x1440 resolution display, and is running Windows 8.1

When I run programs, they do not increase their size in order to account for the small screen.
The only program I have installed that scales correctly is Google Chrome.

[image]

I have the "Disable display scaling on high DPI setting" Unchecked in the compatibility setting of the .exe
I also have the global size of items set to the default extra-large, which is 200%

Here is a list of some programs that I have this problem with:

- Adobe Photoshop
- Abode Illustrator
- Adobe Dreamweaver
- AVG Antivirus 2014 free edition
- Malwarebytes Anti-Malware

Another thing to mention is that some of the text in the program is the proper size.

Any idea how to increase the scaling of these programs?

Comment: Being able to scale correctly is entirely up to the program itself.  Even if the program does scale there is a proper way to do it and an improper way to do it.  Windows also will scale, relaying on that scaling as an application, is the improper way which is what the most recent Adobe Photoshop did.

Comment: So does that mean I can't fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your global size of items set to extra-large (200%) I'm going to assume you actually want things to appear bigger than they are. Your resolution of 2560x1440 makes everything appear smaller.

For a little bit of info before I answer what I think you want, 2560x1440 means you have 2560 pixels in one direction and 1440 in the other direction, this makes everything appear smaller because it has more pixels to use to make it look nice and pretty.

Reduce your resolution, since you have things at 200%, I'm going to assume 800x600 is good for you, it will make everything look nice and big because it has less pixels to play with.

Answer (score 0):

For the Adobe products, try using Dan Antonielli solution on his [website](http://www.danantonielli.com/adobe-app-scaling-on-high-dpi-displays-fix/). This is not a perfect fix as it is going to make some items look blurry but I find it better than squinting.